# I'm not able to Insert New releted contact with with 'Primary Contact' checkbox checked. help me out there

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

[image]

```java
trigger PrimaryContactTrigger on Contact (before delete, before update, before insert) {
    if (Trigger.isBefore) {
        if (Trigger.isDelete) {
            for (Contact con : Trigger.old) {
                if (con.Primary_Contact__c) {
                    con.addError('You cannot delete a Primary contact.');
                }
            }
        }

        if (Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isInsert) {
            Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();
            for (Contact con : Trigger.new) {
                if (con.Primary_Contact__c==true) {
                    accIds.add(con.AccountId);
                }
            }

            if (!accIds.isEmpty()) {
                List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Primary_Contact__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :accIds
                    AND Primary_Contact__c = true and Id not IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()
                ];

                for (Contact con : conList) {
                    con.Primary_Contact__c = false;
                }

                if (!conList.isEmpty()) {
                    update conList;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Trigger.newMap` isn't available in `before insert` triggers.

Before a record has been inserted, it doesn't have an Id, so it can't be put in a map.

- `newMap` is only available in `before update`, `after insert`, `after update`, and `after undelete` triggers.
- `oldMap` is only available in `update` and `delete` triggers.

See the documentation for more details: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm

Answer (score 0):

`Trigger.newMap` is not available in the `before insert` context (only available in after insert, before/after update, and after undelete).

Since you aren't updating the records being triggered (except in the `before delete` context where you're adding an error to prevent deletion), you should be using `after insert` and `after update` as your trigger's contexts.

That'll solve this particular issue.

As a general reminder, `before` triggers are best suited to when you want to make a change to data for the records undergoing DML. This is because `before` triggers allow you to make those changes without the need for DML.